# Unable to select Radiobutton in website using VBA

Tags: vba, radio-button

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Websitedata()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim myURL As String
    myURL = "FIRST PAGE"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate myURL

    Do While ie.readyState <> 4 And ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Selects a type from a dropdown bar
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("dropdownbar").Value = "311"
    'Inputs data
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("inputbox1").Value = ""
    'Inputs data
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("inputbox2").Value = ""
    'Inputs data
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("inputbox3").Value = ""
    'Inputs data
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("inputbox4").Value = ""
    'Inputs data
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("inputbox5").Value = ""
    'Pressed submit and goes to next page.
    ie.document.forms("actionForm").elements("_eventId_Search").Click
    'Needs to press a radiobutton.
    ie.document.getElementByName("declarationId").Click
End Sub
```

I am having issue clicking the radio button. Tried checked, click, value everything.

Here is the HTML of the page:

```
<TABLE id=declarationList class="list sortable" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><TBODY>
<TR class=header>
    <TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" align=center></TH>
    <TH><A onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;" class=sortheader href="">Type<SPAN class=sortarrow sortdir="down">&nbsp;&nbsp;?</SPAN></A></TH>
    <TH><A onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;" class=sortheader href="">rts<SPAN class=sortarrow>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></A></TH>
    <TH><A onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;" class=sortheader href="">tyi<SPAN class=sortarrow>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></A></TH>
    <TH><A onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;" class=sortheader href="">trtjm<SPAN class=sortarrow>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></A></TH>
    <TH><A onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;" class=sortheader href="">erch<SPAN class=sortarrow>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></A></TH>
    <TH><A onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;" class=sortheader href="">dft<SPAN class=sortarrow>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></A></TH>
</TR>
<TR class=evenRow>
    <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" align=center><INPUT onclick="updateButtons('Import','GF','79295876',false,'null',false,true,true,false,false,false)" type=radio value=79295876 name=declarationId> </TD>
    <TD>IM A </TD>
    <TD>4561548 </TD>
    <TD>29/03/2018 </TD>
    <TD>32856 </TD>
    <TD>0313 </TD>
    <TD>40 00 , 40 00 </TD>
</TR>
</TBODY></TABLE>
```

I need it to select the radio button which appears in the next page. Do I have to change some kind of data in the top? Please let me know. I am confused.

Update- Still no answer for this query. Please help

Comment: where is the html for the radio button? what site is this?

Comment: i have given the html for the page already. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a CSS selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[type=""radio""]").Click
```

---

CSS selector tested using HTML supplied:

[image: CSS query]

More about CSS selectors here:  [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

---

**Notes:**

If the page is being refreshed, due to a prior click, then you may need, after that click, to introduce a wait:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,3)
ie.document.querySelector("input[type=""radio""]").Click
```

or,

```
While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend  
ie.document.querySelector("input[type=""radio""]").Click
```

A combination of the above or even a loop, with a timeout, attempting to set the element for clicking:

```
Dim a As Object, exitTime As Date
exitTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set a = IE.document.querySelector("input[type=""radio""]")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Now > exitTime Then Exit Do
Loop While a Is Nothing

a.Click
```

If a new window if opened then you will need to look for that window's handle potentially, or the window with the highest count (most recent). There are methodss on SO detailing this.

Here is an example of looping input tags looking for one with a `type` attribute  of `radio`. This depends on whether you have more than one as to whether it clicks the right one, but gives you an idea.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim n As HTMLDocument
    Set n = New HTMLDocument
    n.body.innerHTML = [A1]  '<== your sample of HTML place in a cell

    Dim aList As Object, item As Object
    Set aList = n.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each item In aList
        On Error Resume Next
        If InStr(item.getAttribute("type").innerText, "radio", 1) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print item.outerHTML
            item.Click
            Exit For
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: What message did you get?

Comment: And is this an internal URL?

Comment: Let me be clear. The first code enters a data and clicks submit. After submitting it moves on to next page that is where the radio button exists.   I think it needs a code that understands that it should find the radio button in the current page rather than searching in old page. Help me in this.

Comment: I added further info in notes section.

Comment: I am getting object doesnt support this property error for this code                        
  """ ie.document.querySelector ("input[type=""radio""]")"""

Comment: Are you on IE 9 or above though I think that may only apply to .querySelectorAll ?

Comment: you could loop the input tags otherwise

Comment: Please give me a example. i am new at this

Comment: Example given above.